# lerna bootstrap fails with "no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, npm, docker-compose, lerna

Trying to run the command

```
lerna bootstrap --hoist
```

On an application I cloned from GitHub. The instructions are to

1. Clone
2. Then run lerna bootstrap --hoist

However, when running the lerna bootstrap --hoist command, each time it fails and I get an error exactly like this but the node module changes each time:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /data/packages/nodes-base/node_modules/arr-filter
npm ERR! dest /data/packages/nodes-base/node_modules/.arr-filter.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/data/packages/nodes-base/node_modules/arr-filter' -> '/data/packages/nodes-base/node_modules/.arr-filter.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I am doing this on a Docker linux container. My frustration lies in the fact that the same setup worked on my previous laptop, but doesn't on this new one I have. My colleague tried this on his Ubuntu machine and it works with no issues.

Comment: what is the version of lerna?

Comment: The version is lerna@3.22.1

Comment: one thing you can try is deleting `node_modules` folder and then use `npm install` and see if the command works or not? or you can only delete `package-lock.json` file and see if that works!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason, but what allowed it to work was switching to the WSL mode on Docker, instead of having it use Hyper-V.